# Change any polygon's colour in a single layer

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox gl js to render coloured (i.e. filled) polygons, whose sources are geojson feature collections. I would like to change the polygon colours on the fly on the client, based on user actions. The following constraints apply/things have been tried:

1. I'm using Mapbox GL JS - not Leaflet, etc.
2. I would like to add all polygons to a single layer (i.e. feature collection per mapbox layer) as adding a new layer for each polygon appears to have a disastrous effect on performance (I have several thousand polygons with several thousand coordinates each), and the
3. It ought to be possible to identify individual polygons by their ID; this is where I struggled as well: I am not sure how to identify all the polygons after they have been added to the layer in the form of a feature collection. Failing that - how can they be identified, if not by ID ?

Please supply a working example that shows at least two polygons being added to a single layer, and their colour being changed after they have been added (random colour is fine, I'm interested in the principle)

Unfortunately, the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146926/mapbox-changing-an-existing-polygons-color), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946850/geojson-mapbox-markers-let-users-change-their-attributes-e-g-color-via-a-but), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022206/polygon-selection-change-color) aren't quite what I need. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282533/change-style-of-single-feature-in-mapbox-gl) comes very close, but doesn't show how to actually apply the change. It simply mentions setStyle()   :-(

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a "choropleth" - polygons color coded by some data property.

> I am not sure how to identify all the polygons after they have been added to the layer in the form of a feature collection.

Make sure each polygon has an id property. In GeoJSON this would be like:

```
"properties": {
    "id": 451,
    "myvalue": 0.8
}
```

You basically have two ways you can do coloring:

1. Store the data separately, and generate a big data-driven property that maps the id onto its required color.
2. Store the data on the feature, and use a small data-driven property that converts the data into a color.

Rather than request a worked example, I suggest you use the API docs to get as close as you can, and ask a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: Steve, thank you for your answer ! It turns out that I hadn't fully understood how mapbox approaches its colouration and data styling. Basically, once I had understood that it depends on the polygon's properties, and "fill-color", "type=interval" and the "stops" directives, everything fell into place.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use data driven styling which lets you use a single Layer but different styles based on the properties of each Feature within that Layer. See an example at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/